# How do I reformat JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Currently my ajax request is getting JSON in this format:

```
    {
        id: 1,
        teamname: "Chicago Blackhawks",
        league: NHL
        wins: 5
        losses: 10
        account_id: 3444,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        teamname: "Chicago Bulls",
        league: NBA
        wins: 15
        losses: 2
        account_id: 3444,
    }
```

but to use an [autocomplete jquery plugin](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/), I need it in this format:

```
[
   { value: 'Chicago Blackhawks', data: { category: 'NHL' } },
   { value: 'Chicago Bulls', data: { category: 'NBA' } }
]
```

Basically I need to only get two fields and format it under value and data -> category instead of name and league. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: _JSON_ is just a notation. Parse it into a native _JavaScript Object_ and then apply any transformations desired as normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data contains some typos, but once you fix those you get:

```
var data  = [{
    id: 1,
    teamname: "Chicago Blackhawks",
    league: "NHL",
    wins: 5,
    losses: 10,
    account_id: 3444,
},
{
    id: 2,
    teamname: "Chicago Bulls",
    league: "NBA",
    wins: 15,
    losses: 2,
    account_id: 3444,
}];
```

From which you can extract your desired list:

```
var newData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    value: d.teamname,
    data: {category: d.league}
  };
});

newData[0];
//=> Object {value: "Chicago Blackhawks", data: "NHL"}
```

*Ack.* Thanks [Salman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5282936/salman-oskooi) for the correction.

Comment: @AndrewD What does your `data` list look like?

Comment: thanks I figured it out and this worked perfectly! I was using a made up data list for this question and I copied your answer which is why it was returning undefined values

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the `data` key in your resulting objects to have object notation you should modify the code from @Hunan's answer just a bit, like so:

```
var newData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    value: d.teamname,
    data: {"category": d.league}
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. I had overlooked the `category`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
var jsonData  = [{
    id: 1,
    teamname: "Chicago Blackhawks",
    league: "NHL",
    wins: 5,
    losses: 10,
    account_id: 3444,
},
{
    id: 2,
    teamname: "Chicago Bulls",
    league: "NBA",
    wins: 15,
    losses: 2,
    account_id: 3444,
}];

function formatJson(jsonData){

  var rslt = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
    rslt.push({ value: jsonData[i].teamname, data: { category: jsonData[i].league} });

   return rslt;
}
```

var mydata = formatJson(jsonData);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `JSON` is valid and @Anik1991 is correct. You can do the following:

```
var json = '{"teams":[{"id": 1,"teamname": "Chicago Blackhawks","league": "NHL","wins": 5,"losses": 10,"account_id": 3444},{"id": 2,"teamname": "Chicago Bulls","league": "NBA","wins": 15,"losses": 2,"account_id": 3444}]}';

// convert your JSON to an object so you can retrieve values you need
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

// create a new array to store your values in the desired format
var newObj = [];

//for each team in obj, push the values you need as an object
obj['teams'].forEach(function(team){
  newObj.push({
    value: team.teamname,
    data: {
      category: team.league
    }
  });
});

// Finally use JSON.stringify to convert newObj to JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/hsxgrom6/